# iOS / Android firebase background sync

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native

I have iOS/Android chat app that stores all the message data in firebase. When user sends message with bad internet connection it goes to firebase cloudstore local storage and then firebase sync data with actual db when internet connection is available and app is in foreground but doesn’t sync from the background.

However for good user experience based on all modern messengers it is expected that message will be sent from app background state when app gets internet connection back.

How do I configure my iOS / Android app or Firebase to achieve background sync?

Comment: This has been covered a few times before, so I recommend checking out https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+sync+in+background

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have seen your name and answers on multiple stackoverflow threads on this topic. I have been reading a lot about this recently. Given a huge amount of experience in this field would you mind to recommend the best approach which you think would work and sync firebase localstorage  to cloudstore for both iOS and Android?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to achieve it in `react-native` but in native android, you can achieve it like below:

**Kotlin:**

```
val scoresRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(room) // room is your chat room
scoresRef.keepSynced(true)
```

**Java**

```
DatabaseReference scoresRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(room);
scoresRef.keepSynced(true);
```

Comment: Thanks, that will work on the background? Any idea if same approach will work for iOS?

Comment: thanks! I was thinking that all app activity is disabled when app is in the background, how does it work then?

Comment: @WildGoat I guess the GOOGLE internal apps keep it synced in the background mode. If my answer helps you please accept the answer :)